# Can I develop Windows 8.1 Phone compatible apps on a Windows 10 PC?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-10

I am aware that there are several changes between Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 with regards to mobile development.

Before I upgrade to Windows 10, I'd like to make sure that I can still develop Windows Phone 8.1 from a Windows 10 PC with VS2013 (Update 5).

Can anyone advise if I will have problems developing 8.1 phone apps with Windows 10?

TIA

Comment: Come on then.... why the vote downs?

Comment: I'm just guessing but probably because this really doesn't have anything directly to do with code.  Personally I'm on the fence, because I don't know where this information is at, but at the same time it's just a yes or no answer.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - Not all questions have to be about code.  Per the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): a question is on topic if it is about: software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still develop Windows Phone 8.1 apps (both Runtime or Silverlight) on Windows 10 with either Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2015 (I'd recommend upgrading to the latter).

Here's a quick snip of Windows Phone 8.1 projects in VS2015 on Windows 10:
[image: Windows Phone 8.1 projects in VS2015 on Windows 10]

Comment: Thank you Rob... You've been a great help!